# Should pointers to memory mapped files be consistent across processes?

Tags: winapi, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I am doing some work that requires interprocess communication. I created a memory-mapped file using CreateFileMapping (using windows API) in one process. In another process I used OpenFileMapping and MapViewOfFile to access the (supposedly) same data. I found that the address of these data are different in each process, is this expected or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is completely expected and normal behavior.

Different processes have different address spaces. A pointer in one process is not valid in another process. What is important is that each process obtains its own local valid pointer to your shared mapping object. When each process wants to access the data inside of the shared mapping object, the access needs to be done using pointers and addresses that are relative to each process.

This is covered in more detail in Microsoft's own documentation: [File Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping)

Comment: " A pointer in one process is not valid in another process" Ah! I didn't know that. Looks like my understanding of pointers is fundamentally flawed. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: One exception is HWND, which is a valid interprocess pointer,

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis an HWND is not a pointer to a memory address, it is a handle into a global kernel table. The API uses a pointer to hold the handle value, but it is not a real pointer that you can dereference to access data